# Delete All Files In a Directory Without Deleting Symbolic Links and the Files They Point To

Tags: linux, hyperlink, find, rm

In a specific directory, I'd like to be able save symbolic links and the files to which they point while deleting the rest.

Example: /home/me/test_dir ls

mylink
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

Over time "mylink" had pointed to file1.txt, then file2.txt and now file3.txt

mylink -> /home/me/test_dir/file3.txt

What line command can I execute to delete just file1.txt and file2.txt? I have about 800K files I need to delete.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to delete ONLY real files that don't have a symbolic link pointing to them? Are you concerned about symlinks from other places than just this one particular directory?

Comment: @Shawn Question 1: Yes, Question 2: No.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a script that deletes regular files from a directory if there are no symlinks in that directory that point to them.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Usage: perl rmlinks.pl DIRECTORY

use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use Cwd qw/abs_path/;

my $dirname = shift;
opendir(my $dir, $dirname);
chdir $dirname;
my %referenced;

while (my $file = readdir $dir) {
  $referenced{abs_path(readlink $file)} = 1 if -l $file;
}

rewinddir $dir;
while (my $file = readdir $dir) {
  unlink $file if -f $file && ! -l $file && !exists $referenced{abs_path $file};
}

closedir $dir;
```

It tries to account for both absolute and relative symlink paths, but use at your own risk.